# CKEditor how to stop partial (font) styles from displaying in markup?

Tags: ckeditor4.x, font-style

I believe we are currently using version 4.17 (not sure why not on 5?...anyways)

Anyways.. **when copying and pasting from a word document**, *we normally get a huge mess of SPAN tags repeated over and over*.  (In version 4.1 I dont recall seeing this.. in v4.17 it is everywhere).

After some searching. I added in the config parameter to remove ALL font style form word paste.

```
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;
```

At first glance.. this seemed to work..  but then I noticed tings left over like:

```
<span calibri=""><span arial="">blah blah blah</span></span>
```

1.) Wouldnt this be part of the 'font' styles?  (family)
2.) These arent even legit tags (so how is this happening?)
3.) What is the fix for this?

Also, after using:

```
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;
```

How can I still allow 'color' styles to come through?  (not the main puporse, but curious if you can 'extraAllowedContent' things after the 'pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles' action?

Updated:
Wow.. (crickets? interesting)

To recap:

After adding this:

```
 config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;
```

I am still getting this:

```
<span calibri=""><span arial="">blah blah blah</span></span>
```

In other random word docs pasting from.. I am seeing things like this:  (which I have no clue how to address?  not a class or style or attribute)

```
<!--[if--><!--[endif]-->&nbsp;<!--![endif]--><!--![if-->
```

Why?  And how do I fix this?

thanks

Comment: Nobody?  Seems like pasting bullet lists from word document also creates:


<ul>
 <li><!--[if--><!--[endif]-->